# Unable to load DLL 'CpuMathNative' on published website

Tags: c#, asp.net, machine-learning, ml.net, somee

I just deployed my ASP.net website which uses ML.net on a free web host called Somee.
Before deploying the solution, everything was working fine and all was published without struggle but the moment I clicked the button I have to submit the input to the MLModel, the website gave me the following error message:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'CpuMathNative': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I already verified if all the references in the Visual Studio project were on the bin folder of the website which they are.

Additional details were given:

> [DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'CpuMathNative': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)]
> Microsoft.ML.Internal.CpuMath.Thunk.SumSqU(Single* ps, Int32 c) +0
> Microsoft.ML.Internal.CpuMath.CpuMathUtils.SumSq(Single mean, ReadOnlySpan`1 src) +183 Microsoft.ML.Transforms.Mapper.L2Norm(ReadOnlySpan`1 values, Single mean) +39
> Microsoft.ML.Transforms.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__5(VBuffer`1& dst) +113 Microsoft.ML.Data.<>c__DisplayClass20_0`1.b__0(VBuffer`1& dst) +182 Microsoft.ML.Data.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`2.b__0(TDst& dst) +22
> Microsoft.ML.Data.PredictedLabelScorerBase.EnsureCachedPosition(Int64& cachedPosition, TScore& score, DataViewRow boundRow, ValueGetter`1 scoreGetter) +45 Microsoft.ML.Data.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<GetPredictedLabelGetter>b__0(UInt32& dst) +31 Microsoft.ML.Transforms.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetMappingGetter>b__0(TValue& dst) +24 Microsoft.ML.Data.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`2.b__0(TRow row) +22
> Microsoft.ML.Data.TypedRowBase.FillValues(TRow row) +37
> Microsoft.ML.Data.RowImplementation.FillValues(TRow row) +13
> Microsoft.ML.PredictionEngineBase`2.FillValues(TDst prediction) +45 Microsoft.ML.PredictionEngine`2.Predict(TSrc example, TDst& prediction) +89
> Microsoft.ML.PredictionEngineBase`2.Predict(TSrc example) +64
> SampleClassification.Model.ConsumeModel.Predict(ModelInput input) in C:\Users\pinky\source\repos\ProjetctBoMa\SampleClassification.Model\ConsumeModel.cs:30
> ProjetctBoMa._Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\pinky\source\repos\ProjetctBoMa\ProjetctBoMa\Default.aspx.cs:28
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9796242
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +211
> System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +12
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +15
> System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1696

What should I do?